# How to get the part of string coming after first word and underscore from the given string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, file, substring, substr

Following is one variable that contains the string:

```
 $msg ='file_fafe9add9c26415689ffcfbc000d7751.docx';
```

I don't want initial part(**i.e. file_**) from the file name below. It should come as follows :

```
$msg ='fafe9add9c26415689ffcfbc000d7751.docx';
```

How could I achieve it in PHP in an efficient and best way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [strstr](http://php.net/strstr)

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Use a mix of [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/strpos) and [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/substr).

Comment: This isn't necessarily the best case for it, but lets say you need `$prefix` and `$fileName`, you could use `$parts = explode('_',$msg); $prefix = $parts[0]; $fileName = $parts[1];`.

Comment: @Jakar Add the limit of 2 to the `explode()` and it would be the solution I'd go for as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str_replace('file_', '', $msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this substring like that:

```
$msg ='file_fafe9add9c26415689ffcfbc000d7751.docx';
$msg = substr($msg,strpos($msg,'_')+1);
echo $msg;
```

Comment: [Just make sure that an underscore is always present, or you'll have problems](https://eval.in/301189). (to avoid this, make sure you only use `substr` if the `strpos` result isn't `FALSE`)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
$piece = explode('_', $string, 2)[1];
```

This code makes one important assumption.

```
1.  There is at least one _ in the string
```

If you can safely make this assumption it's a fun snippet to use.

Comment: You can eliminate the second assumption by using the `limit` parameter of the `explode()` function

Comment: @kingkero Great point. I've never used the limit parameter before. I'll apply your feedback to my answer.